# How to remove all digits after . value except two digits c#

Tags: c#, string

I am getting string value like `123.00000000`.
Now I want to take only 123.00 value. So how can I remove all last digits except two digits after value.
For example:

`textBox1.Text="123.00000000";`    I want like `textBox1.Text="123.00";`
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string str = "123.00000000";
textBox1.Text = str.Substring(0,str.IndexOf(".")+3);
```

Comment: Does not work when the decimal separator of the number is not `.` like here in germany since i assume that also the string value is a numeric string.

Answer (score 3):

Use the proper string format.

```
double value = double.Parse("123.00000000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
textBox1.Text = value.ToString("N2");
```

[**Standard Numeric Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/QuZpyq)

**Edit**: The `string.Substring` has the problem that only half of the world uses the `.` as decimal separator. So you need to know the culture in which the input was converted from a number to a string. If it's the same server you can use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` (or omit it since that is the default):

```
double originalValue = 123;
// convert the number to a string with 8 decimal places
string input = originalValue.ToString("N8");
// convert it back to a number using the current culture(and it's decimal separator)
double value = double.Parse(input, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
// now convert the number to a string with two decimal places
textBox1.Text = value.ToString("N2");
```

Comment: Please note that rounding may occur when using this method.

Answer (score 1):

see [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) for a complete overview of how to format numbers. In your case it is:

```
textBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", 123.0);
```

Comment: Sir your code working  if i give values like123.00000.. But I hav a string like 

string str="123.0000000";
In this case it is not working